# Moving record from one table to another via datagridview

Tags: sql, datagridview, vb.net-2010

I want to be able to click a record in my datagridview which has Selected all records from `tbl_requested-shifts` and when a button is clicked, this record is removed from `tbl_requested_shifts` and moved into `tbl_shifts`, can anyone help me with the SQL for this task?

By the way I am coding in vb.net 2010

Comment: you need to supply a lot more detail about the table structure, and the code you've tried.  The SQL will basically look like `INSERT INTO tbl_shifts (col1, col2, col3) select col1, col2, col3 FROM tbl_requested_shifts`

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tested it but i think it will work.

Whenever a row is selected in the DataGridView, get a *primary key column* value from it. And let's assume that 1st column is the *primary key column* and it is an *integer* type.

I have put the code int *CellClick* event. You can use *CellContentClick* event but i find *CellClick* more reliable. Make sure that *MultiSelect* property of *DataGridView* is set to *false*

```
Dim value as Integer

 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        Try
            value = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
 End Sub
```

Now, In the *click event* of Button. Have a *group of query* like following.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_shifts (col1, col2,col3,col4)
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4
FROM tbl_requested_shifts
WHERE col1 =value;
DELETE FROM tbl_requested_shifts
WHERE col1=value;
```

Try it. Thanks.

**ADDITIONAL**

```
objCommand = New SqlCommand
objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_shifts (col1, col2,col3,col4) " & _
"SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 " & _
"FROM tbl_requested_shifts " & _
"WHERE col1 =" & value & ";" & _
"DELETE FROM tbl_requested_shifts " & _
"WHERE col1=" & value & ";"

 Try
        <your sql connection object>.Open()
        command.Connection = <your sql connection object>
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        <your sql connection object>.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        <your sql connection object>.Close()
End Try
```

The above *T-SQL statement* will *add a row* in one table and *remove a row* from other table. And make sure that you *reload* the *datagridview* after executing this code. Thanks.

Comment: sorry I have no experience with Group Query SQL, how do I execute this? Thanks for your help

Comment: @CharlesForbes: just put the statement in the CommandText property. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

## 2 Answer

Make a separate function for delete the record from table1 and call it in the button_click event after moving the record from table1 to table2 as shown below. Hope this will work...

```
 Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
       
    Try
         Call Connect()

         STRSQL = "Insert into table2 select * from table1 where" & _ 
                  "id=" & TextBox1.Text & ""
         myCmd = New OleDbCommand(STRSQL, myConn)
         myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
         myConn.Close()

         Deletedata()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub Deletedata()
    Call Connect()

    STRSQL = "delete from table1 where ID=" & TextBox1.Text & ""
    myCmd = New OleDbCommand(STRSQL, myConn)
    'myConn.Open()

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(myCmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        da.Fill(dt)
        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConn.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```